# Java: Read many values from one string

Tags: java, string

Say if I have the string "George:45:185" that contains the information Name:age:height about a person; how would I go about reading these values individually from the string? The solution seems to be to separate the string at the ":" symbol and after that reading the values individually, but I can not get it to work.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: "*but I can not get it to work*" can we see your code? Use [edit] option to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#split` to separate the parts.

```java
var str = "George:45:185";
var parts = str.split(":");
String name = parts[0];
int age = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
int height = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use the `split()` method of the String class to split the string into an array of substrings based on a specified delimiter. In your case, you can split the string using the `colon (":") delimiter` as follows:

```
String info = "George:45:185";
String[] values = info.split(":");
```

This will create an `array value` that contains three elements: "George", "45", and "185". You can then access these values individually using `array indexing`:

```
String name = values[0];
int age = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
int height = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
```

*Note that if you need to convert the age and height strings to integers, then you have to use the `parseInt()` method of the `Integer class`.*